# C - почему &arr не равно arr и как мы получаем размер?

Tags: c++, c

```
int  arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
```

Помогите понять, каким образом у нас `arr` - это массив(указатель на первый элемент массива).
А вот `&arr` - это указатель на весь целочисленный массив из 6 элементов.
Что есть тогда указатель `&arr` на весь массив при условии, что в `size` мы получаем размер массива.
Как указатель `&arr` может указывать на весь массив?

Пример нашел [тут](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-size-of-array-in-cc-without-using-sizeof-operator/), но понять как тут работает адресная арифметика пока не могу.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`arr` имеет тип `int [6]` - массив из 6 элементов `int`, это **не** указатель на первый элемент. Соответственно `&arr` имеет тип `int ( * ) [6]` - указатель на массив из 6 элементов `int` (тот самый "указатель на весь целочисленный массив"). В выражении `*(&arr + 1) - arr` сначала при сложении происходит адресная арифметика с указателем на массив из 6 элементов `int`, при этом указатель рассматривается как указывающий на первый элемент массива, элементы которого имеют тип `int [6]`, далее результат `(&arr + 1)` разыменовывается и получается `int ( & ) [6]` - ссылка на массив из 6 элементов `int` и наконец при вычитании происходит адресная арифметика с двумя массивами из 6 элементов - для этого создаются два временных объекта - указатели на первые элементы этих массивов.

Проверить, что есть что, можно используя `std::is_same`:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int arr []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int [6]      , decltype(arr         )>);
    static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int ( * ) [6], decltype(&arr        )>);
    static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int ( * ) [6], decltype(&arr + 1    )>);
    static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int ( & ) [6], decltype(*(&arr + 1) )>);
    static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int *        , decltype(+arr        )>);
    static_assert(::std::is_same_v<int *        , decltype(+*(&arr + 1))>);
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBLSAA6oCoRODB7evnoJSY4CQSHhLFExUraY9jkMQgRMxARpPn5cpeUpVTUEeWGR0XoK1bX1GU197Z0FRRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQmy24EAJ5xmAD6BMRMhAo72CYaAIK3d8EEmywXDBCTjyYA7Fb3twAnM9NjViNsAKxWCEAEV%2BFiamzMpE2yxR0k2EJRADZfnDlv8HhpASNHMhjkwFEpahAQCA%2Bug6XgFMcFKwTgA3HZuEEmKG42GbIXClFYdYHI4QMHCmVCr7LbDywlA0l4cmU6kEWn0giMkDM1ns45c3YgiCbABUm0mkIsAphosw4sOmAg5mx0tlcuuSu%2BxNV6qp0S1dIZTJZbLYxu5Zst1tt9sdzsl7ul1k2XBl8sVO2V/uqZIpQZpod14cNUZNPMEm3N7vjfLtfIdmzFtAlrotbrMHuI4PTXBt2d9APzTELGuD2rD%2BojRqrIKtXs2SfbLu7Fk9XuHub9JILaqLmunZdnFc5MZrS69q47G67qb720sGcmO4Je%2BImAIcwYmw0u4Aj8cL3Bw0y0JwEK8H4HBaKQqCcG41jpgoszzJgz7LDwpAEJoYHTAA1iAEIaPonCSNBeHwZwvAKCApG4bBYGkHAsAwIgKCoCwcR0NE5CUGg3G8TEwBcFwyI0O20R0RAERUREwQ1PsnDYYJbCCAA8gwtDKUxpBYG8RjiHp%2BBfg4eAcpgdF6ZgqhOl4BCLNhzxlFRtB4BE5zEPsHhYFRZx4CwKnMVQBjAAoABqeCYAA7hpRwwdh/CCCIYjsCUyXyEoahUboTQGEYKDIZY%2BgeXRkDTKgcQVNZAC0tUMjsMKmJY1hcD8my1QA6mItCdV1RzoIYZK0WUToVC4DDuJ4DT%2BFNYzdMUpBZMkAiDI0y2JKtDALYUPTDGN5kCG0AwzUMzTja0/QdMEXR7UtIynekG2PTd%2BSLVMMxzAsehnJgTnMRBHBQaQMFwQhHCqAAHNitXYpImzAMgyAZlwAB0Zi1khrUlZsuCECQmGIh4Qn0P2ZhYZMvCMVob6kERJFkRwFGkEFjNg7wEO0fROF4dMrEcbMBBxA5/EQIJPFk/4%2BBEEtmWpeIGWyIoKjqHpf0A6QMXnHEwXgZBlF6RDGkOSLLyoFQmzQ7D8OI8jqMY1jXGS9ERNU7zTF0wgmBMFgMSfEzLNs6RHPURw3MMXzhHEaRQPLIb4M0R7tP6xwZgJ5zSc0/hpCWcQSTOJIQA%3D%3D)

Comment: Проверка азов языка (имею ввиду std::is_same_v) лишнее.

Answer (score 3):

```
int  arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
```

- Массив `arr` имеет тип `int [6]`, т.е. массив из шести элементов типа `int`.
- Выражение `&arr` имеет тип `int (*)[6]`, т.е. указатель на (массив из шести элементов типа `int`).
- В выражении `&arr + 1` к указателю применяется арифметика указателей. Значение указателя наращивается на `sizeof(int[6])` байт, что равно `sizeof(int) * 6` байт. Получившийся указатель указывает на гипотетический массив из шести элементов типа `int`, следующий непосредственно за массивом `arr`.
- В выражении `*(&arr + 1)` происходит разыменование указателя. Т.е. мы получаем lvalue «ссылающееся» на гипотетический массив после массива `arr`<sup>UB-1)</sup>. Тип этого выражения  — `int[6]`<sup>3)</sup>.
- В выражении `*(&arr + 1) - arr` оба операнда бинарного оператора `-` имеют тип массива  — `int [6]`. И к обоим операндам применяется неявное преобразование из типа массива к типу указателя на первый элемент массива.
  Т.е гипотетический массив `*(&arr + 1)` после массива `arr` типа `int [6]` преобразуется к указателю типа `int*` на свой первый элемент.
  Аналогично массив `arr` преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент.
- Разность двух указателей типа `int*` даёт знаковое целочисленное значение типа [std::ptrdiff_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t), равное количеству объектов типа `int` между двумя указателями<sup>UB-2)</sup>.

---

1. Разыменование указателя на гипотетический элемент после массива вызывает **неопределённое поведение**, так как такой указатель не является указателем на объект.

[basic.compound / 3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3):

> ... Every value of pointer type is one of the following:
>
> - a *pointer to* an object or function (the pointer is said to *point* to the object or function), or
> - a *pointer past the end of* an object ([expr.add]), or
> - the *null pointer value* for that type, or
> - an *invalid pointer value*.

[expr.unary.op / 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1):

> The unary `*` operator performs *indirection*: the expression to which it is applied shall be *a pointer to an object type*, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an *`lvalue` referring to the object* or function to which the expression points.

Код

```
constexpr static int  arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
constexpr std::ptrdiff_t diff = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
```

может вызвать следующую [ошибку компиляции](https://rextester.com/NDK24145):

```
//cannot access array element of pointer past the end of object
constexpr std::ptrdiff_t diff = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
                                ^
```

Даже если бы было известно, что по адресу на который указывает указатель на гипотетический элемент после последнего расположен объект, то такой указатель по прежнему нельзя разыменовывать. Код

```
constexpr static int arr[2][2] = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}};
constexpr int val = arr[0][2];
```

может вызвать следующую [ошибку компиляции](https://rextester.com/RCXN46065):

```
//read of dereferenced one-past-the-end pointer is not allowed in a constant expression
constexpr int val = arr[0][2];
                    ^
```

2. Разность двух указателей, указывающих на элементы разных массивов, вызывает **неопределённое поведение**.

[expr.add / 5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#5):

> When two pointer expressions `P` and `Q` are subtracted, the type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as `std​::​ptrdiff_­t` in the `<cstddef>` header.
>
> - If `P` and `Q` both evaluate to null pointer values, the result is `0`.
> - Otherwise, if `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, array elements `i` and `j` of the **same array object** `x`, the expression `P - Q` has the value `i − j`.
> - Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>   [Note 1: If the value `i − j` is not in the range of representable values of type `std​::​ptrdiff_­t`, the behavior is undefined. — end note]

Код

```
constexpr static int arr[2][2] = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}};
constexpr const int* p00 = &arr[0][0];
constexpr const int* p10 = &arr[1][0];
constexpr std::ptrdiff_t diff = p10 - p00;
```

Может вызвать [ошибку компиляции](https://rextester.com/OEHX5256):

```
//subtracted pointers are not elements of the same array
constexpr std::ptrdiff_t diff = p10 - p00;
                                    ^
```

3. Результат разыменования указателя на тип `T` — это lvalue типа `T` (не ссылка).

[expr.unary.op / 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1):

> The unary `*` operator performs *indirection*: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the **result is an lvalue** referring to the object or function to which the expression points. **If the type of the expression is “pointer to `T`”, the type of the result is “`T`”**.

Выражение наподобие `std::is_same_v< int ( & ) [6], decltype(*(&arr + 1)) >` возвращает `true` в силу особенностей работы спецификатора `decltype`, который для `lvalue` типа `T` в качестве типа выводит `T&`.

[dcl.type.decltype / 1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1):

> For an expression `E`, the type denoted by `decltype(E)` is defined as follows:
> ...
> otherwise, if `E` is an lvalue, `decltype(E)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `E`;
> ...

---

Итого: приведённый в вопросе код содержит неопределённое поведение. Результат его выполнения (если вообще скомпилируется) не предсказуем.

Comment: Что "это"???????

Comment: Я специально добавил `constexpr`, т.к. стандарт обязывает детектировать неопределённое поведение в константных выражениях. Если я уберу `constexpr` из примеров кода, то что по вашему это должно доказать?

Comment: Собственно, не совсем понятно, что конкретно вы пытаетесь оспорить. Сформулируйте точнее, с каким утверждением из ответа вы не согласны.

Comment: godbolt.org/z/8xaWTnx17 — что должен опровергнуть данный пример кода? В ответе я указал, что код _может_ не компилироваться, но не сказал, что обязан. Более того, на практике, код содержащий UB, как раз таки компилируется, но это никак не отменяет наличие неопределённого поведения 
Да, большая часть моего ответа сосредоточена на UB. Предлагаете игнорировать UB? Использование `constexpr` демонстрирует, что компилятор явно знает про UB, и его игнорирование  [чревато неприятными последствиями](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c78a930d281d7fa), даже если код успешно компилируется.

Comment: Вот к чему (оценка в -1) приводит ненавистное народу гипотетическое UB. Собственно, наверное, говоря об UB такого типа, надо иметь в виду, что реальная прога при физическом доступе к памяти за массивом может грохнуться, если этот виртуальный адрес будет недоступен в таблице трансляции MMU (например, такое реально может произойти при играх с mmap)